# "findViewById" not working in ViewPagerIndicator Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator, findviewbyid

Hi there I have managed to bind my XML files to the ViewPagerIndicator by extending them as Fragments but I cannot use the essential findViewById code to reference my button to the code. This is my code as it is can someone help

```
    package com.example.sliding;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class twoey extends Fragment {

    Button lol;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, null);
        return v;

        lol = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);

    }
}
```

But what ever I try to do I cannot get the little red wriggly line of the ***findViewById*** word can someone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 2 errors:

1. `return v;` must be the last line of a method, any line after that cannot be run! **is unreachable** so there is a compiler error!
2. the line  `lol = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);` needs to be `lol = (Button) v.findViewById (R.id.button1);` or you are going to have a `NullPointerException` because `button1` is part of `View v` and not the activity.

The right code is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, null);

    lol = (Button) v.findViewById (R.id.button1);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but then I get a big red squiggly line on the whole line which does not fix the problem

Comment: Place this line above return

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler simply can't access code written after the `return` statement. `return` means you're done with the method and you're returning a value from it, so there's no sense in executing something after that. So you need to simply move the `lol = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1)` (which as a matter of fact should be called as `lol = (Button) v.findViewById (R.id.button1)`, since `v` is your root view) before the `return v` call, and the code will compile properly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onViewCreated()`. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    lol = (Button) getView().findViewById (R.id.button1);

    .... // ANY OTHER CASTS YOU NEED TO USE IN THE FRAGMENT
}
```